# What is the meaning of xargs show limits output

Tags: shell, command-line, xargs, posix

You can use xargs to discover limits about the commandline you're using:

```
$ xargs --show-limits
Your environment variables take up 1901 bytes
POSIX upper limit on argument length (this system): 2093203
POSIX smallest allowable upper limit on argument length (all systems): 4096
Maximum length of command we could actually use: 2091302
Size of command buffer we are actually using: 131072
```

However, I don't understand the difference between `Maximum length of command we could actually use` and `Size of command buffer we are actually using`. What do both of these limits mean, and which one is the actual limit we're facing on the length of the commandline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's what it says on the tin: “Maximum length of command we could actually use” is the maximum possible command line length, given the limit on the platform where `xargs` is running and the space taken up by the environment. This value only depends on the platform configuration and the environment. “Size of command buffer we are actually using” is the size that this invocation of `xargs` is using. It can't be more than the maximum, but it can be less. By default, `xargs` doesn't use the maximum, but a [“sensible” default](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/tree/lib/buildcmd.c?id=v4.6.0#n551) determined at compile time and capped by platform limits, normally 128 kB. The actually-using size can be changed with the `-s` option.

Comment: So the "we" in "we are actually using" is xargs, not the user or its environment. Does this mean that if we are not using xargs, our limit is 2091302?

Comment: @ChieltenBrinke Even if you are using xargs, your limit is 2091302. You have to pass the `-s` option to make it use memory.

Comment: I meant to ask, when we are not using xargs, which of the two limits do we face?

Comment: @ChieltenBrinke 2091302 is the limit. 131072 is the default value used by xargs.